# "Invalid validator function: unique" shows up even though I register as a new user

Tags: javascript, validation, sequelize.js, postman

This is my code

```
User.init({
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      validate: {
        isEmail: {
          args: true,
          msg: "Invalid email format"
        },
        notEmpty: {
          args: true,  
          msg: 'Cannot be blank'
        },
        unique: {
          args: true,
          msg: "Email must be unique"
        }
      },
    }
```

I check using Postman. I register as a new user but the "Invalid validator function: unique" shows up instead of being registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unique` option is not a part of the `validate` option, it should be outside on the same level as `validate`:

```js
User.init({
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: {
        args: true,
        msg: "Email must be unique"
      },
      validate: {
        isEmail: {
          args: true,
          msg: "Invalid email format"
        },
        notEmpty: {
          args: true,  
          msg: 'Cannot be blank'
        }
      }
    }
```